# What does the following Jquery do?

Tags: jquery

```
ApplyClickableLinkToClass = function(selectedElements) {
    // Go through each of the passed in selections and try to apply a link to them
    $.each(selectedElements, function() {
        var linkElement = $("a:first:not(.do-not-apply-clickable-link)", $(this));
        var link = linkElement.attr("href");

        if (!IsNullEmptyOrUndefined(link)) {
            $(this).click(function(firstLink) {
                var divToLink = firstLink;
                return function() {
                    $(divToLink).unbind('click');
                    if (divToLink.attr("target") != "_blank") {
                        window.location = link;
                        return false;
                    }
                };
            } (linkElement));
        }
    });
}
```

Called as follows :

```
ApplyClickableLinkToClass($j(".rc_blueBtn, .rc_whiteBtn:not(.More)"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// loop over all selectedElements
$.each(selectedElements, function() {
    // find the first (a) that doesn't have the
    // class ('do-not-apply-clickable-link')
    // in the currently iterated element
    var linkElement = $("a:first:not(.do-not-apply-clickable-link)", $(this));

    // retrieve the matched (linkElement) href
    // attribute and store it in (link)
    var link = linkElement.attr("href");

    // bind click event to the currently iterated
    // element if the (link) was defined...
    if (!IsNullEmptyOrUndefined(link)) {
        $(this).click(function(firstLink) {
            var divToLink = firstLink;
            return function() {
                $(divToLink).unbind('click');
                if (divToLink.attr("target") != "_blank") {
                    window.location = link;
                    return false;
                }
            };
        } (linkElement));
    }
});
```

Comment: So it adds the link to the div from the inside first href it finds ?

Comment: No, it adds an event to the to each of the `selectedElements` only if the `link` is not `IsNullEmptyOrUndefined` ...

Comment: Correct, it opens *a new* window **and** removes the click handler on the element. Thus, if you click on it again, it shouldn't open a new window...

Comment: It doesn't open in a new window though

Comment: Im not sure I was just looking at methods which were causing the IE Script running error, and this was one of them

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8943/discussion-between-xander-and-stevieb)